# TypeScript: Sort Array 1 by indexOf value from Array 2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I'm new to Typescript/JavaScript so I'm sure I'm missing something easy.

I have an array of 2 types, each of which has a sub-array of 3 - 4 names:

```
myArray = [
{
    "type": "abc",
    "names": {
        "Jane Smith": 5,
        "John Doe": 3,
        "Jack Jones": 2
    }
},
{
    "type": "xyz",
    "names": {
        "Jane Smith": 3,
        "John Doe": 7,
        "Jack Jones": 3
    }
}
];
```

I need to know which main type has the highest overall total and show that first.  In this example "xyz" has the highest total ((3 + 7 + 3) vs. (5 + 3 + 2)). So I'd want to display xyz before abc.

I am successfully getting the totals of the two and putting them into a new array called totalValues:

```
totalValues = [
{
    "type": "xyz",
    "count": 13            
    }
},
{
    "type": "abc",    
    "count": 10            
    }
}
];
```

The problem is that I need to sort my original array (myArray) by type based on the total and I can't figure it out.

```
let sortedTotalValues = totalValues.sort().reverse();    //highest value first

let sortedGroupNames = null;

sortedGroupNames = myArray.sort((a, b) => {            
    return sortedTotalValues[0].indexOf(a) - sortedTotalValues[0].indexOf(b);
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const myArray = [
{
    "type": "abc",
    "names": {
        "Jane Smith": 5,
        "John Doe": 3,
        "Jack Jones": 2
    }
},
{
    "type": "xyz",
    "names": {
        "Jane Smith": 3,
        "John Doe": 7,
        "Jack Jones": 3
    }
}
];
const sum =   (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

const total = x=>Object.values(x.names).reduce(sum)

console.log(myArray.sort((a,b)=>(total(b)-total(a))))
[Codepen here][1]


  [1]: https://codepen.io/drGreen/pen/eYmbeze
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
let myArray = [
  {
    "type": "abc",
    "names": {
       "Jane Smith": 5,
       "John Doe": 3,
       "Jack Jones": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "xyz",
    "names": {
       "Jane Smith": 3,
       "John Doe": 7,
       "Jack Jones": 3
    }
  }
];

let modifiedArray = myArray.map(obj => {
  let total = 0;
  for (var property in obj.names) {
    total += obj.names[property];
  }
  return {
    ...obj,
    totalNamesValue: total // Added totalNamesValue which stores the total
  }
});

let sortedArray = modifiedArray.sort((a, b) => b.totalNamesValue - a.totalNamesValue)

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you try to find first the index of the element based on the `type` property with [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) then you can push it into the right place in the final array.

Maybe you can try with the following:

```js
const myArray = [{"type":"abc","names":{"Jane Smith":5,"John Doe":3,"Jack Jones":2}},{"type":"xyz","names":{"Jane Smith":3,"John Doe":7,"Jack Jones":3}}];

const countsInOrder = myArray.map(({type, names}) => ({
  type,
  count: Object.entries(names).reduce((a, [k,v]) => a + v, 0)
})).sort((a,b) => b.count - a.count);

const result = new Array(myArray.length);

myArray.forEach(e => {
  const index = countsInOrder.findIndex(a => a.type === e.type);
  result[index] = e;
});

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Given an array and a sorting criteria you can simply feed in your criteria into the `.sort(...)` method as a function.

```js
myArray = [
{
    "type": "abc",
    "names": {
        "Jane Smith": 5,
        "John Doe": 3,
        "Jack Jones": 2
    }
},
{
    "type": "xyz",
    "names": {
        "Jane Smith": 3,
        "John Doe": 7,
        "Jack Jones": 3
    }
}
];

myArray.sort((a,b) => {
  let sumA = Object.values(a["names"]).reduce((total, curr) => total + curr, 0);
  let sumB = Object.values(b["names"]).reduce((total, curr) => total + curr, 0);
  
  return sumB -sumA;
});

console.log(myArray);
```

**Note**: This does have the overhead of recalculating the sum everytime it makes a comparision this can be improved by simply substituting the `sumA` and `sumB` variables to get the value from a precomputed array shown below

```js
myArray = [
{
    "type": "abc",
    "names": {
        "Jane Smith": 5,
        "John Doe": 3,
        "Jack Jones": 2
    }
},
{
    "type": "xyz",
    "names": {
        "Jane Smith": 3,
        "John Doe": 7,
        "Jack Jones": 3
    }
}
];

let total = myArray.map( el => 
  Object.values(el["names"]).reduce((total, curr) => total + curr, 0));
  


myArray.sort((a,b) => {
  let sumA = total[myArray.findIndex( el => el["type"] === a["type"] )];
  let sumB = total[myArray.findIndex( el => el["type"] === b["type"] )];
  
  return sumB - sumA;
});

console.log(myArray);
```